# Laravel fetch from MySQL error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I want to make a small localhost website that fetch products using MySQL.

After I researched and apply some answers I still have issues:

Trying to get property of non-object (View: 
F:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

**web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    //return view('welcome');
    $products = DB::table('laravel_products')->pluck('product_name', 'product_about', 'producer_ID', 'product_added');
    return view('welcome', ['products' => $products]);
});
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Product name</td>
                                <td>Description</td>
                                <td>Date added</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php

                        foreach ($products as $value) {
                            echo '
                                <tr>
                                    <td>' . $value->product_name . '</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            ';
                        }

                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

What should I do to fetch from MySQL?

Comment: `$value['product_name']` as pluck would return an array not an collection object

Comment: I tried so and the result is: Illegal string offset 'product_name' (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //return view('welcome');
    $products = DB::table('laravel_products')->select('product_name', 'product_about', 'producer_ID', 'product_added')->get();
    return view('welcome', compact('products'));
});


<table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Product name</td>
                                    <td>Description</td>
                                    <td>Date added</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                         @if(isset($products))
                            @foreach($products as $value)
                           
                                    <tr>
                                        <td> {{$value->product_name}}</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: I think you are close, but still says: Use of undefined constant products - assumed 'products'

Comment: @PanameraTurboS Wait check it

Comment: It works, was a missing "$": Route::get('/', function () {
    //return view('welcome');
    $products = DB::table('laravel_products')->select('product_name', 'product_about', 'producer_ID', 'product_added')->get();
    return view('welcome', compact($products));
});
But doesn't show any products

Comment: @PanameraTurboS No no

Comment: @PanameraTurboS its mistake of quote

Comment: I shouldn't add the $ sign ?

Comment: @PanameraTurboS change return view('welcome', compact('products')); instead of return view('welcome', compact(products));

Comment: @PanameraTurboS Please check with updated answer and please remove $ sign and check it

Comment: Now works like magic! thank you so much @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd!!

Comment: @PanameraTurboS Glad to help

Comment: @PanameraTurboS If my answer is your solution then please accept my naswer and upvote to my answer

Comment: @PanameraTurboS welcome and please up vote to my answer

Comment: @PanameraTurboS Thanks a lot